# Tycho doesn't include root files in updatesite

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2, tycho

I'm trying to build an eclipse feature using tycho.  It has some binary dependencies defined as rootfiles in the build.properties file:

```
root.win32.win32.x86=rootfiles/win32/
root=rootfiles/all/
```

The feature builds fine and has two .zip artifacts for the two root folders I defined.

However, I also build an updatesite for the feature using the `eclipse-update-site` tycho directive.  The update site target folder builds correctly, but the root zips aren't included, just the feature .jar and the plugin .jars.

Is there a way to include root files in update sites using tycho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use packaging type eclipse-repository instead, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-repository

Comment: Thanks!  That worked, but it only added the binaries for the platform I built it on (win32).  If I add root.macox.cocoa... it isn't building binaries for that platform.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand why tycho was producing a shallow .zip file for my update site (no plugins/, no features/). Using eclipse-update-site instead of eclipse-repository fixed the problem. Then I saw that eclipse-update-site packaging was deprecated and understood tycho expects an update site file named "category.xml" NOT "site.xml" as Eclipse new update site project wizard creates (doc: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/eclipse-repository).